# Acceder a cualquier path relativo como un parámetro

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando montar un gestor de archivos WEB con soporte para rutas *virtuales*; es decir, no habrá un único directorio *raiz*, sino que se partirá de una *colección*. Cada una de estas *colecciones* se montará en un *middleware* diferente:

> index.js

```
const express = require( 'express' );

const photos = new( require( './src/photos.js' ) )( '/Compartido/Imágenes' );
const music = new( require( './src/music.js' ) )( '/Compartido/Música' );

const app = express( );

app.use( '/fotos', photos.middleware ); // Colección de fotos.
app.use( '/musica', music.middleware ); // Colección de música.
...

app.listen( PORT, HOST );
```

Puesto que la cantidad de subdirectorios es, en principio, arbitraria, estoy intentando acceder a **toda** la URL relativa solicitada, para poder *particionarla* y trabajar con ella:

> src/photos.js

```
class Photos {
    get middleware( ) { return this.$router; }

    get path( ) { return this.$path; }

    constructor( path ) {
        this.$path = path;
        this.$router = require( 'express' ).Router( );

        this.$router.get( '/index.html', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveRoot( req, res, next ) );
        this.$router.get( '/', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveRoot( req, res, next ) );

        // ESTA LÍNEA //
        this.$router.get( '/:url', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveUrl( req, res, next ) );
    }
}
```

Esto **no funciona**. Si intento acceder con el navegador a

> /photos/unaimagen.jpg

Mi manejador `$serveUrl( )` **no se llama**.

Lo mismo ocurre para cualquier ruta que esté por debajo de la *colección*:

> /photos/unaimagen.jpg
> /photos/level1/unaimagen.jpg
> /photos/level1/level2/unaimagen.jpg

**Ninguna** de estas peticiones llama a mi manejador.

He intentado establecer un manejador distinto por cada *profundidad*:

```
this.$router.get( '/*/*/:url', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveUrl( req, res, next ) );
this.$router.get( '/*/:url', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveUrl( req, res, next ) );
this.$router.get( '/:url', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveUrl( req, res, next ) );
```

Pero el resultado es el mismo: mi manejador **no se llama**.

¿ Como puedo acceder a cualquier *sub-ruta* y obtenerla como un parámetro ?

Comment: ¿Has probado cambiar el orden de los *midleware* de tal forma que el que maneja el directorio raíz sea el último?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear un conjunto de funciones [*middleware*](https://expressjs.com/es/guide/using-middleware.html) de [Express](https://expressjs.com) para manejar un conjunto de rutas parametrizadas. Sin embargo, al implementar la solución se tiene el siguiente comportamiento:

```js
/* ejemplo de rutas:
ruta raíz:
  /
rutas parametrizadas
  /:param
  /subruta/:param
  /:param1/:param2
  /:param1/subruta
  /:param1/subruta/:param2
  /:param1/subruta/:param2/subruta2
*/
this.$router.get( '/index.html', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveRoot( req, res, next ) ); // <- funciona
this.$router.get( '/', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveRoot( req, res, next ) ); // <- funciona

// ESTA LÍNEA //
this.$router.get( '/:url', ( req, res, next ) => this.$serveUrl( req, res, next ) ); // <- nunca entra aquí
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

El problema descrito ocurre por el orden de la declaración de las funciones *middleware*.

Express analiza la cadena correspondiente al parámetro de ruta y hace una comparación con la ruta solicitada en la petición. Esta comparación no es estricta, ya que una solicitud puede contener caracteres adicionales como parte de una [`URL Query String`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Por lo tanto la verificación realizada debe garantizar que la ruta base (la ruta hasta la última aparición del carácter `/`) exista o haya sido declarada como tal en alguna de las fucniones *middleware*, devolviendo `match` en la primera que consiga.

Esto indica que si tengo un *middleware* para manejar una ruta raíz, declarado **antes** de otro *middleware* para manejar una subruta de la misma ruta raíz, Express usará el primer *middleware*, ya que el mismo hará `match` durante el análisis de la ruta.

Así, un *middleware* de la siguiente forma:

```
  this.$router.get( '/', (req, res, next) => { ... });
```

Se encargará de manejar todas las solicitudes a la ruta raíz, sin importar lo extenso o diferente de las subrutas.

Es decir, todas las siguientes solicitudes serán manejadas por el *middleware* anterior:

```sh
GET /
GET /subruta
GET /param1
GET /subruta/param1
GET /param1/?key=value
GET /long/path/of/differents/length/and/:params
```

Conociendo este comportamiento, debemos escoger muy bien el orden en que declaramos nuestros *middleware* en Express. Una de las reglas (no escritas) que siempre uso para estos casos es el uso de la llamada *escalera invertida*, que consiste en declarar en primer lugar las rutas más largas y de último las más cortas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
this.$router.get('/:param1/subruta/:param2/subruta2', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/:param1/subruta/:param2', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/:param1/subruta', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/:param1/:param2', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/subruta/:param', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/subruta', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/:param', (req, res, next) => { ... });
this.$router.get('/', (req, res, next) => { ... });
```

De esta forma, garantizamos que el análisis de las rutas en cascada es efectivo al momento de decidir la función *middleware* apropiada para la ruta solicitada.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Este mecanismo, **enfoque** de declaración de rutas funciona también aunque con diferencias obvias de sintaxis para [tag:zendframework] Y adicionalmente, resuelve problemas similares. (+1) y te agradecería insinuar en la respuesta que podría ser útil para otros frameworks que emplean modelos MVC.